# My iOS app shows login screen after some inactivity

Tags: ios

I have an iOS app that works beautifully, save for a weird issue with the log-in screen.

The app logs in by sending credentials to the back end. On a successful log-in a token is returned to the app which then uses that token for all future requests. The token has a very long lifetime.

Basically, I want the user to be logged in until he logs out explicitly.

The problem is that after some time of inactivity when I then go to the app, it has gone back to the login screen.

I find this very weird. As I mentioned the token is valid for a long time, and even so just switching to the app after some time of inactivity doesn't trigger any communitcation with the backend anyway.

So I am wondering if it has something to do with the view hiearchy? The login screen presents - on successful log in - a controller modally which then handles everything from then on (it is the paperfold menu controller: https://github.com/honcheng/PaperFoldMenuController).

Any ideas? I feel there is something quite simple I have overlooked...

Comment: Not enough detail I'm afraid. Without seeing how the app is put together, and what triggers it to "go back to the login screen", there is nothing anyone can do to help you.

Comment: store your login credentials NSUserDefaults in key value pair and when user tap logout button then clear same key value pair from NSUserDefaults - by doing this login session can be manageged locally

Comment: Not enough info what triggers login screen to appear

Comment: post the code u tried, description is not enough to figure out the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Much appreciated. I will try to see what happens in the life cycle method as described by Muhammad in the answer below, and then update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What simply comes to my mind is that iOS clears the App data from memory & relaunches the app again which causes your app to re-initialize.

You should implement some logic in the below methods to store your credentials & reuse them on app launch:

```
– application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
– application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
– applicationDidBecomeActive:
– applicationWillResignActive:
– applicationDidEnterBackground:
– applicationWillEnterForeground:
– applicationWillTerminate:
– applicationDidFinishLaunching:
```

I recommend storing the user credentials in `– applicationWillResignActive:` and clear the stored credentials in `– applicationWillTerminate:`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks Muhammad I will try to see what happens in these methods. I makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Just to follow up: It seems you are correct. After looking more at it, it seems iOS closed the app due to "memory pressure". The app itself wasn't using much memory (23 MB), but by using a lot of different app I could force the termination. I did as you mention: save the credentials in keychain and auto-log-in the user when the app re-initialized. Thanx for steering me in the direction.

Comment: you are more than welcome :)